# Default value on a custom WPF control

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls, dependency-properties

Here is my problem. I recently created a custom control, which works pretty well.
But i have a problem when i use it, i have a little problem :

In my control, i made a property named Value, defined like this :

```
 public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(int), typeof(NumericUpDown), new PropertyMetadata(1000));
    public int Value
    {
        get
        {
            return (int)GetValue(ValueProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ValueProperty, value);
            this.ValueText.Text = value.ToString();
        }
    }
```

When I do a databinding to this value, the binding works, but the default value is set to 1000, so it first print 1000. But actually, the property bound to Value isn't equal to 1000.
I would like to print in `ValueText.Text` the value of the bound property when the Value property is created.

Edit : Question is simple, how can I remove that default value and directly print the bound property ?

Comment: I don't see a question mark anywhere in this jumble.

Comment: Oh, hm, well, sorry >< (question added)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to setup a `PropertyChanged` event in your DependancyProperties metadata to update `ValueText` when `Value` changes.

somthing like this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(int), typeof(NumericUpDown),
    new PropertyMetadata(1000, (sender, e) => (sender as NumericUpDown).ValueText.Text = e.NewValue.ToString()));

public int Value
{
    get { return (int)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The property setter will not get called as things change via WPF's data binding, so this technique will not work.

The default, initial value will always be 1000, but data binding may override it.  You will need to add a [Callback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.propertychangedcallback.aspx) to appropriately notify you when the dependency property value is changed.

For details, see the [Dependency Property Callbacks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745795.aspx#Coerce_Value_Callbacks_and_Property_Changed_Events) page to see how to implement a property changed callback correctly.  This is the appropriate place to set your other (`ValueText`) property.